# PHP seems to be executing both if and else whilst using Securimage Captcha

Tags: php, if-statement, validation, captcha

I'm trying to use a PHP captcha to validate a contact form on a site and I've hit a brick wall for the past few days where the form works fine on FF, Chrome, Safari but not IE. I've searched loads of posts on here but haven't found anything that seems to solve my issue, so I'm hoping some of you experts can give me a hand here :). The fact this is only on IE has me baffled as the only problem I can think of would be the session vars, which seem to work fine in ie.

Below is the main code that validates the captcha code sent by my contact form. I should point out that the captcha code is defintely being sent by post as I've checked the headers and the code: `var_dump($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']))` returns true and false correctly when the captcha code is correct or incorrect, as you'd expect.

The main problem seems to be that if the captcha code is entered correctly and `$securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code'])` is returning true on IE, the statement `if ($captcha_result == FALSE)` is being executed BUT also sending the email using the mail() function within the corresponding else. For some reason the `$formSent = 2;` doesn't seem to be getting run within the else where the mail() function is. I've tried a combination of if and else values, allsorts with no luck. It's got to be a user error on my part somewhere...

```
<?php
session_start();
include('securimage/securimage.php');


        if (isset($_POST['query_form'])) {


            if ($_POST['name'] == "Your name" || $_POST['email'] == "Your E-mail" || $_POST['message'] == "Message") {
                $formSent = 1; //display the notification bar wth error.
            } 
            else {

                //validate the captcha code now.
                $securimage = new Securimage();
                //var_dump($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']));
                $captcha_result = $securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']);


                //ERROR - IE runs the first if and the mail function below for some reason.
                if ($captcha_result == FALSE) {
                    $formSent = 3; //display the notification bar wth captcha error.    
                }

                else if ($captcha_result !== FALSE) {               
                    $to = 'email';
                    $subject = 'subject';
                    $message = "Name: " .  $_POST['name'] . "\r\n" . "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "Phone: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\r\n" . "Message: " . $_POST['message'] ;
                    $headers = 'From: email' . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";


                    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                    $formSent = 2; //display the notification bar with success.     

                }
            }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Never do ` if ($captcha_result == FALSE) {...} else if ($captcha_result !== FALSE) {`. Find the bug (probably a testing problem here) instead of trying voodoo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, voodoo was my last ditch effort :D. Tried changing the statements to if ($captcha_result == TRUE) with a corresponding else. Fine on all browsers but IE still, where it's doing the same thing - any idea why part of the if and part of the else are both being executed?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how both if and else clauses could be executed. That's the reason why I suppose there's a testing problem (delay, double request, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, you were spot on with the double request! Odd that it was only IE, but fixed it now :)